# Selenium/Python/Flash - How?

Tags: python, flash, selenium

I'm using Selenium with Python to test a web application. The app has a Flash component that I'd like to test. The only references I've seen to using Selenium with Flash refer to Flash-Selenium which hasn't been updated in several years. Is testing Flash with Selenium even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have been in your situation before.  The truth is that this is hard to accomplish with selenium.  I've bookmarked

```
http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2014/12/17/programming-a-bot-to-play-the-sushi-go-round-flash-game/
```

for the next time I run into this problem, but I have not actually needed it since then.  But I think there is a solution using that link + selenium.

Would love an update if you find a way to make this work!

Comment: This link is down now, currently I'm using the cached version.
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2R5wuduppdsJ:inventwithpython.com/blog/2014/12/17/programming-a-bot-to-play-the-sushi-go-round-flash-game/
just if anyone else would be reading this

Comment: there is also [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919222640/http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2014/12/17/programming-a-bot-to-play-the-sushi-go-round-flash-game/) cache, which may be more permanent (although the original link is live atm)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have access to the flash source code it is possible (although it requires some work).  To do that you have to expose the flash actions you want to test using selenium.  This requires that you make the methods available in Flash to execute via Javascript.  Once you can do that, you should be able to automate the process with using selenium's ability to execute javascript.